# C: Splitting a string into two strings, and returning a 2 - element array

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strtok

I am trying to write a method that takes a string and splits it into two strings based on a delimiter string, similar to .split in Java:

```
char * split(char *tosplit, char *culprit) { 

    char *couple[2] = {"", ""};

    int i = 0; 

    // Returns first token  
    char *token = strtok(tosplit, culprit);    


    while (token != NULL && i < 2) { 
        couple[i++] = token; 
        token = strtok(NULL, culprit); 
    } 

    return couple;
}
```

But I keep getting the Warnings:

```
In function ‘split’:
warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return couple;
            ^~~~~~
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

... and of course the method doesn't work as I hoped.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am also open to other ways of doing this besides using strtok().

Comment: Function return type is `char *` and you are returning an `array of char*`

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable, as the warning says. You must not do that. You need to dynamically allocate an array or take one as an argument. Plus you claim to return a single string, not an array of strings.

Comment: `couple` goes out of scope on function exit, in fact no longer exists.

Comment: Do you want independent copies of the parts of the string or are pointers into the original string sufficive?

Comment: @Swordfish I am looking for independent copies.

Comment: Then `strtok()` is not the function you need - it modifies the original string and returns pointers into the original buffer.  You should define your required semantics _in the question_ rather then comments.  None of the current answers generate independent copies, not unreasonably since you explicitly ask for a solution using `strtok()`.

Comment: @Clifford It doesn't have to be strtok(). I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: The title _still_ explicitly mentions `strtok()`.  However the point is that you made a comment that suggests that `strtok()` is not even a viable solution. So rather then inviting other solutions, you should explicitly ask for a solution that meets your required semantics (while specifying those semantics).

Comment: @Clifford The title has been changed upon your recommendation!

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace  : yet still not incorporated the part about independent copies mentioned in a comment.  All your requirements should be in the question.  That said, changing the question significantly after some in good faith have attempted to answer the original question might not be considered good practice. Sometimes better to start a new question.  Here your question was simply about what you did wrong, not a request for a different solution.  The accepted answer does not create independent copies in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd caution your use of strtok, it probably does not do what you want it to. If you think it does anything like a Java split, read the man page and then re-read it again seven times. It is literally tokenizing the string based on any of the values in delim.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* split( char* s, char* delim ) {
  char* needle = strstr(s, delim);

  if (!needle)
    return NULL;

  needle[0] = 0;
  return needle + strlen(delim);
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "Fluffy furry Bunnies!";
  char* res = split(s, "furry ");
  printf("%s%s\n", s, res );
}
```

Which prints out "Fluffy Bunnies!".

Comment: When you set the first character of needle to NULL, you're doing the exact same thing that `strtok` does.

Comment: Yes and no. This does follow the C tradition of modifying the original string, but it splits based on a string delimiter (per Java).

Answer (score 2):

A view things:

First, you are returning a pointer to a (sequence of) character(s), i.e. a `char
*` rather than a pointer to a (sequence of) pointer(s) to char. Hence, the return type should be `char **`.

Second, you return the address of a local variable, which - once the function has finished - goes out of scope and must not be accessed afterwards.

Third, you define an array of 2 pointers, whereas your `while`-loop may write beyond these bounds.

If you really want to split into two strings, the following method should work:

```
char ** split(char *tosplit, char *culprit) {     
    static char *couple[2];
    if ((couple[0] = strtok(tosplit, culprit)) != NULL) {
        couple[1] = strtok(NULL, culprit);
    }
    return couple;
}
```

Comment: This seems like it will just return 2 pointers to the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner Wouldn't this return the original string itself at the couple[0] position?

Comment: The semantics differ slightly from what appear to be the original intent, where failure to find _any_ delimiter, results in two empty strings.  This design is however simpler, returning at least one string and a NULL pointer in the second if there is no delimiter.  I think this is better, but there may have been a reason for the original semantics.

Comment: Your third point is not the case; the loop condition `i < 2` ensures that only `couple[0] and `couple[1]` are written.

Comment: When I try to use your method from main like this: 
char *result = *split("what/in", "/");
printf("%c\n", result[0]);
printf("%c\n", result[1]);

I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace Change your format specifier from `%c` to `%s` in the `printf` calls.

Comment: @bruceg that is what I previously had and it still crashed. :(

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace : You cannot pass a _literal string constant_ to the function since `strtok()` must modify it.  See the example in my answer, where the string const is used to initialise a char array which is then passed to the function.  Again it is an artefact of your requirement to use `strtok()`.

Comment: you can't pass in static strings... call it something like this: `char *str = strdup("foobar and barfoo");`, `const char *culprit = " ";`, `char **split_str = split(str, culprit);`
`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `strtok` modifies the memory of `tosplit`  so be certain that, that's what you wish to do.  If so then consider this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 
 * NOTE: unsafe (and leaky) implementation using strtok
 *
 * *into must point to a memory space where tokens can be stored
 * or if *into is NULL then it allocates enough space.
 * Returns:
 *  allocated array of items that you must free yourself
 *
 */


char **__split(char *src, const char *delim)
{
    size_t idx = 0;
    char *next;
    char **dest = NULL;


    do {
        dest = realloc(dest, (idx + 1)* sizeof(char *));
        next = strtok(idx > 0 ? NULL:strdup(src), delim);
        dest[idx++] = next;
    } while(next);


    return dest; 
}


int main() {
    int x = 0;
    char **here = NULL;
    here = __split("hello,there,how,,are,you?", ",");

    while(here[x]) {
        printf("here: %s\n", here[x]);
        x++;
    }

}
```

You can implement a much safer and non leaky version (note the `strdup`) of this but hopefully this is a good start.

Comment: All names starting with two underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. You are free to ignore this rule in your own code (and suffer the consequences) but please don't do it here where it is likely to be copied by people who don't know better.

Answer (score -2):

The type of `couple` is `char**` but you have defined the function return type as `char*`.  Furthermore you are returning the pointer to a local variable.  You need to pass the pointer array into the function from the caller.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char** split( char** couple, char* tosplit, char* culprit ) 
{ 
    int i = 0; 

    // Returns first token  
    char *token = strtok( tosplit, culprit);    

    for( int i = 0; token != NULL && i < 2; i++ ) 
    { 
        couple[i] = token; 
        token = strtok(NULL, culprit); 
    } 

    return couple;
} 

int main()
{
    char* couple[2] = {"", ""};
    char tosplit[] = "Hello World" ;

    char** strings = split( couple, tosplit, " " ) ;

    printf( "%s, %s", strings[0], strings[1] ) ;

    return 0;
}
```